# Hide requests sent through URL after QR scan

Tags: http, qr-code

I intend to have a web application which can be accessed only after scanning a QR code from mobile. So, once the user scans the QR code, they will be redirected to the underlying URL, where in they give their userid and password and upon successful login, I update my database. I don't want to create a mobile app for scanning - they should scan using their own QR scanner mobile app.

The problem here is , I don't want them to be able to copy this URL and paste it in their browser window the next time - navigation to the URL should always happen after QR code scan. How can I achieve this? Is there a way I can make HTTP requests from QR scan as POST instead of GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A QR code just contains a string of letters and numbers.  If the string starts with `http://` or `https://` then the QR scanner will treat it as a URL.  There is no way to make it POST, nor to hide any data from the user.

If you want, you can make the code "one time only".

Let's say your URL is `https://example.com/?1234`

Once the code has been scanned, you can record in your database that `1234` has already been used.

Or you can put a button on that page, an tell the user they have to click it in order to use the code.